# Function returns undefined in cypress.io

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

The following code works fine in a test.

```
cy.get("table").find(`tr[data-index=0] > :nth-child(1)`).then($td => { 
    cy.get("input").type($td.text().trim() + "{enter}");
});
```

But this one, same code but wrapped in a function, won't

```
const getResult = () => {
    cy.get("table", {timeout: 60000}).find(`tr[data-index=0] > :nth-child(1)`, {timeout: 60000}).then($td => {
        return $td.text().trim()
    });
}

it("query", () => {
    cy.get("input").type(getResult() + "{enter}");
})
```

what am I missing about `then()` in cypress?

**The aim is, of course, getting the content of the first cell of the table and type it in `input` field.**

EDIT:
following @jean-smaug suggestion, I tried this `invoke/as`
but I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`. Indeed the function is in a different ES module and the context is different. The code:

```
// different ES module
export const getResult = () => {
    cy.get("table").find(`tr[data-index=0] > :nth-child(1)`).invoke("text").as("text")
} 

// test
getResult("opencga-file-grid")
cy.get("input").type(this.text + "{enter}");
```

Comment: This page from the documentation might be useful https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values you can't return like this from cy.get()

Comment: Not sure what the previous comment is talking about, `cy.get()` doesn't take a function. You certainly can return a new subject from `cy.then()`. See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then#Yields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last example works if you drop the alias and treat the return value as a Cypress Chainable.

```js
// different ES module
export const getResult = () => {
  return cy.get("table").find(`tr[data-index=0] > :nth-child(1)`).invoke("text");
} 

// test
getResult("opencga-file-grid")
  .then(text => {
    cy.get("input").type(text + "{enter}");
  });
```

Equivalent to this (if all code was in the same file)

```
cy.get("table").find(`tr[data-index=0] > :nth-child(1)`).invoke("text")
  .then(text => {
    cy.get("input").type(text + "{enter}");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how to access variable in Cypress.

This part of the doc should be helpfull

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context

I guess you can do something like this

```js
cy.get("table", {timeout: 60000}).find(`tr[data-index=0] > :nth-child(1)`, {timeout: 60000}).invoke('text').as('text')

cy.get("input").type(this.text + "{enter}");
```

Comment: do I really need something like that? I'm just returning a value from a function, not sharing data between tests

Comment: Yes I think you'll have to do like this.

Even if there is a **then**, it's not really promise. So you'll not get the return value even if you use await

https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#Can-I-use-the-new-ES7-async-await-syntax

Comment: Try by putting your code outside of the getResult function